# MongoDb find with nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Lets say I have this kind of collection

```
{
    "_id" :"A",
    "title" : "TITLE1",
    "brand" : [ 
        {
            "brand_id" : "B",
            "varients" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "RED ",
                    "price" : 5.0
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "brand_id" : "C",
            "varients" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "GREEN",
                    "price" : 5.0
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "brand_id" : "D",
            "varients" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "Others",
                    "price" : 0.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

I then want to select one and ONLY the nested data of variants. Have tried with the following statement without any success.

```
db.testing.findOne(  {_id: "A", "brand.brand_id" : 'D'} )
```

Expected output

```
 "varients" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "Others",
                    "price" : 0.0
                }
            ]
```

Comment: When calling Mongo from the application layer, you typically would return the entire document and extract the JSON there.

Answer (score 0):

Using `findOne` you can't get the subset or nest content of the document in the response, but yes using aggregation you can get it in a way you want it

Check out this aggregation pipeline:

```json
[
  {
    '$match': {
      '_id': 'A'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$brand'
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'brand.brand_id': 'D'
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'varients': '$brand.varients', 
      '_id': 0
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Just wondering why you need the $unwind here.?

Comment: As the brand is an array and we want only one element from that array for that array. Here `unwind` can help which will create a document for each element of an array and then we can filter out document which we want